# Selenium + RSpec parallel tests within multiple browsers

Tags: selenium, rspec, automated-tests

I'm implementing automated tests using Selenium with Ruby and RSpec, and I faced a problem when tried to run tests in parallel within multiple browsers.
I just described setup and teardown methods in spec_helper.rb like this:

```
  browsers = %w[chrome firefox]
  browsers.each do |browser|
    config.before :context do
      @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for browser.to_sym
      @driver.manage.window.maximize
      @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 5
    end

    config.before(:example) { @page = Home_page.new @driver }
  end

  config.after(:context) { @driver.quit }
```

But when I run code with *parallel_rspec spec/home_page.rb*, I see - both browsers start, but tests execute in the second one only (firefox), in chrome nothing happens - even base_url doesn't load. And when done - both browsers closed.
Is there a way to implement such logic?